# Fetch data from db to list separate with bracket [row1],[row2] python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this data on field "encoding" on db

row 1:

```
-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219
```

row 2:

```
-0.01662210404872894 0.04337024807929993 0.01862039864063263 -0.052526746839284897 -0.0401001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.036789832413196564 -0.4461588442325592 0.02734302967786789 -0.15894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219
```

then query the data fetch to list like this:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
list_db = [list(i) for i in result]
```

I got this result :

```
[['-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219'], ['-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219']]
```

I want to remove the single quote "'" from [[''],['']] and want to remove outside brackets like this [],[], final result :

```
[-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219], [-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219]
```

so every row will separate [datarow1], [datarow2] ...

I have try with this :

```
new_encoding = [" / ".join([item for sublist in list_db for item in sublist])]
```

but that return :

```
['-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.3200435340
4045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120
815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680
786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.0556
86019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.071190051734
44748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0
.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510
462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173
179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917
 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219 / -0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.068
62039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.1407351
1958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645
342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798
877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.116
7166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.0695106759667
3965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.0352886430919170
4 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.0294
99150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.02406684
4955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.0668544918298721
3 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219']
```

any advices ?

Comment: can u provide the two rows in df form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` is a list of strings.

```
a = '-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219'
b = '-0.01662210404872894 0.04337024807929993 0.01862039864063263 -0.052526746839284897 -0.0401001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.036789832413196564 -0.4461588442325592 0.02734302967786789 -0.15894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219'

result = [[a,b]]
>>result
['-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219', '-0.01662210404872894 0.04337024807929993 0.01862039864063263 -0.052526746839284897 -0.0401001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.036789832413196564 -0.4461588442325592 0.02734302967786789 -0.15894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398    -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219']
```

and when you create 
`list_db = [list(i) for i in result]`, you are creating a list of list of a string which represents the `[''] (Single quotes and square brackets)`.

```
[['-0.08662210404872894 0.07337024807929993 0.06862039864063263 -0.012526746839284897 -0.0801001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.046789832413196564 -0.1461588442325592 0.08734302967786789 -0.14894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219', '-0.01662210404872894 0.04337024807929993 0.01862039864063263 -0.052526746839284897 -0.0401001787185669 -0.05193192511796951 -0.036789832413196564 -0.4461588442325592 0.02734302967786789 -0.15894044399261475 0.32004353404045105 -0.043585460633039474 -0.18398809432983398 -0.1360706388950348 0.010066289454698563 0.14073511958122253 -0.1879929006099701 -0.10926008969545364 -0.038104988634586334 0.0051414333283901215 0.12177332490682602 0.042124710977077484 0.06387297809123993 -0.0010835491120815277 0.007938936352729797 -0.40603896975517273 -0.11739332228899002 -0.09416411072015762 0.04884645342826843 -0.10451817512512207 -0.0636964812874794 -0.03207370266318321 -0.22111159563064575 -0.0585072860121727 -0.010224942117929459 0.01382109522819519 -0.027572423219680786 -0.05739714950323105 0.18291768431663513 -0.043999649584293365 -0.17532485723495483 0.02261991798877716 0.03303423896431923 0.21171262860298157 0.11194954067468643 0.07195933908224106 -0.0157555490732193 -0.1303720623254776 0.0822707861661911 -0.11768637597560883 0.055686019361019135 0.09667232632637024 0.1132042184472084 0.013476325199007988 0.02152293547987938 -0.1167166605591774 0.012514045462012291 0.04955602437257767 -0.1576307713985443 0.013799342326819897 0.08811783790588379 -0.08696464449167252 -0.06506940722465515 -0.07119005173444748 0.253802627325058 0.02371562272310257 -0.09664812684059143 -0.16254350543022156 0.06951067596673965 -0.06556420773267746 -0.054225075989961624 0.09485962241888046 -0.16375689208507538 -0.18442556262016296 -0.23735365271568298 0.041585199534893036 0.41791266202926636 0.02714100480079651 -0.20061111450195312 0.013660889118909836 -0.07566389441490173 -0.03528864309191704 0.15228623151779175 0.11166317760944366 0.03392065316438675 0.016384199261665344 -0.15302486717700958 0.08743089437484741 0.14507059752941132 -0.11160030215978622 -0.05510462075471878 0.19224773347377777 -0.03552474081516266 0.10947123914957047 0.004576046019792557 0.029499150812625885 -0.04130791872739792 0.07367254793643951 -0.12816789746284485 0.002003241330385208 0.07023963332176208 0.010513385757803917 -0.06864386796951294 0.06988558173179626 -0.09394612908363342 0.07096806913614273 0.019971150904893875 -0.008061941713094711 0.024066844955086708 -0.07938322424888611 -0.12111519277095795 -0.07080638408660889 0.04778080806136131 -0.2768844962120056 0.21204794943332672 0.15829457342624664 0.05094699561595917 0.1492161601781845 0.033130403608083725 0.05755796283483505 -0.01276221964508295 -0.06685449182987213 -0.2827809751033783 -0.020659975707530975 0.13686902821063995 0.04191699996590614 0.08146911859512329 -0.03575839102268219']]
```

You need to parse the string to get what you need. You can split the string using spaces with `split()` then convert each element to float using `map()`. Finally, create a `list()` from the resulting map. So your `list_db` becomes

```
list_db = [list(map(float,i.split())) for j in result for i in j]
print(list_db)
```

You get

```
[[-0.08662210404872894, 0.07337024807929993, 0.06862039864063263, -0.012526746839284897, -0.0801001787185669, -0.05193192511796951, -0.046789832413196564, -0.1461588442325592, 0.08734302967786789, -0.14894044399261475, 0.32004353404045105, -0.043585460633039474, -0.18398809432983398, -0.1360706388950348, 0.010066289454698563, 0.14073511958122253, -0.1879929006099701, -0.10926008969545364, -0.038104988634586334, 0.0051414333283901215, 0.12177332490682602, 0.042124710977077484, 0.06387297809123993, -0.0010835491120815277, 0.007938936352729797, -0.40603896975517273, -0.11739332228899002, -0.09416411072015762, 0.04884645342826843, -0.10451817512512207, -0.0636964812874794, -0.03207370266318321, -0.22111159563064575, -0.0585072860121727, -0.010224942117929459, 0.01382109522819519, -0.027572423219680786, -0.05739714950323105, 0.18291768431663513, -0.043999649584293365, -0.17532485723495483, 0.02261991798877716, 0.03303423896431923, 0.21171262860298157, 0.11194954067468643, 0.07195933908224106, -0.0157555490732193, -0.1303720623254776, 0.0822707861661911, -0.11768637597560883, 0.055686019361019135, 0.09667232632637024, 0.1132042184472084, 0.013476325199007988, 0.02152293547987938, -0.1167166605591774, 0.012514045462012291, 0.04955602437257767, -0.1576307713985443, 0.013799342326819897, 0.08811783790588379, -0.08696464449167252, -0.06506940722465515, -0.07119005173444748, 0.253802627325058, 0.02371562272310257, -0.09664812684059143, -0.16254350543022156, 0.06951067596673965, -0.06556420773267746, -0.054225075989961624, 0.09485962241888046, -0.16375689208507538, -0.18442556262016296, -0.23735365271568298, 0.041585199534893036, 0.41791266202926636, 0.02714100480079651, -0.20061111450195312, 0.013660889118909836, -0.07566389441490173, -0.03528864309191704, 0.15228623151779175, 0.11166317760944366, 0.03392065316438675, 0.016384199261665344, -0.15302486717700958, 0.08743089437484741, 0.14507059752941132, -0.11160030215978622, -0.05510462075471878, 0.19224773347377777, -0.03552474081516266, 0.10947123914957047, 0.004576046019792557, 0.029499150812625885, -0.04130791872739792, 0.07367254793643951, -0.12816789746284485, 0.002003241330385208, 0.07023963332176208, 0.010513385757803917, -0.06864386796951294, 0.06988558173179626, -0.09394612908363342, 0.07096806913614273, 0.019971150904893875, -0.008061941713094711, 0.024066844955086708, -0.07938322424888611, -0.12111519277095795, -0.07080638408660889, 0.04778080806136131, -0.2768844962120056, 0.21204794943332672, 0.15829457342624664, 0.05094699561595917, 0.1492161601781845, 0.033130403608083725, 0.05755796283483505, -0.01276221964508295, -0.06685449182987213, -0.2827809751033783, -0.020659975707530975, 0.13686902821063995, 0.04191699996590614, 0.08146911859512329, -0.03575839102268219], [-0.01662210404872894, 0.04337024807929993, 0.01862039864063263, -0.0525267468392849, -0.0401001787185669, -0.05193192511796951, -0.03678983241319656, -0.4461588442325592, 0.02734302967786789, -0.15894044399261475, 0.32004353404045105, -0.043585460633039474, -0.18398809432983398, -0.1360706388950348, 0.010066289454698563, 0.14073511958122253, -0.1879929006099701, -0.10926008969545364, -0.038104988634586334, 0.0051414333283901215, 0.12177332490682602, 0.042124710977077484, 0.06387297809123993, -0.0010835491120815277, 0.007938936352729797, -0.40603896975517273, -0.11739332228899002, -0.09416411072015762, 0.04884645342826843, -0.10451817512512207, -0.0636964812874794, -0.03207370266318321, -0.22111159563064575, -0.0585072860121727, -0.010224942117929459, 0.01382109522819519, -0.027572423219680786, -0.05739714950323105, 0.18291768431663513, -0.043999649584293365,
-0.17532485723495483, 0.02261991798877716, 0.03303423896431923, 0.21171262860298157, 0.11194954067468643, 0.07195933908224106, -0.0157555490732193, -0.1303720623254776, 0.0822707861661911, -0.11768637597560883, 0.055686019361019135, 0.09667232632637024, 0.1132042184472084, 0.013476325199007988, 0.02152293547987938, -0.1167166605591774, 0.012514045462012291, 0.04955602437257767, -0.1576307713985443, 0.013799342326819897, 0.08811783790588379, -0.08696464449167252, -0.06506940722465515, -0.07119005173444748, 0.253802627325058, 0.02371562272310257, -0.09664812684059143, -0.16254350543022156, 0.06951067596673965, -0.06556420773267746, -0.054225075989961624, 0.09485962241888046, -0.16375689208507538, -0.18442556262016296, -0.23735365271568298, 0.041585199534893036, 0.41791266202926636, 0.02714100480079651, -0.20061111450195312, 0.013660889118909836, -0.07566389441490173, -0.03528864309191704, 0.15228623151779175, 0.11166317760944366, 0.03392065316438675, 0.016384199261665344, -0.15302486717700958, 0.08743089437484741, 0.14507059752941132, -0.11160030215978622, -0.05510462075471878, 0.19224773347377777, -0.03552474081516266, 0.10947123914957047, 0.004576046019792557, 0.029499150812625885, -0.04130791872739792, 0.07367254793643951, -0.12816789746284485, 0.002003241330385208, 0.07023963332176208, 0.010513385757803917, -0.06864386796951294, 0.06988558173179626, -0.09394612908363342, 0.07096806913614273, 0.019971150904893875, -0.008061941713094711, 0.024066844955086708, -0.07938322424888611, -0.12111519277095795, -0.07080638408660889, 0.04778080806136131, -0.2768844962120056, 0.21204794943332672, 0.15829457342624664, 0.05094699561595917, 0.1492161601781845, 0.033130403608083725, 0.05755796283483505, -0.01276221964508295, -0.06685449182987213, -0.2827809751033783, -0.020659975707530975, 0.13686902821063995, 0.04191699996590614, 0.08146911859512329, -0.03575839102268219]]
```